# Vue.js: Unmuting v-if Video Embed Throws 'Unmuting Failed...the user didn't interact with the document before'

Tags: vue.js, video, nuxt.js

In my Vue app I have a 'screensaver' that appears after a few minutes of inactivity. At which point a muted, autoplaying Vimeo iframe is faded in on v-if. This works fine.

But my problem occurs when I try to unmute. On top of the video element I have an unmute button, when I've gone to test this I get the error:
'Unmuting failed and the element was paused instead because the user didn't interact with the document before.'

But the unmute event is trigged by a click...

Any help on this would be appreciated.

```
<template>
  <transition name="video">
    <div
      v-if="showScreensaver"
      class="video-container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
      :class="{ blur: showScreensaver }"
    >
      <transition name="mute">
        <div v-if="!muteButtonHide" @click="toggleMute" class="button-mix">
          <img
            id="volume-button"
            src="@/assets/img/volume-mute.svg"
            alt=""
          /></div>
      </transition>

      <iframe
        id="vimeo-player"
        title="vimeo-player"
        src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/my-video-id&amp;controls=0"
        frameborder="0"
        allowfullscreen
      ></iframe></div
  ></transition>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import Player from "@vimeo/player";

const showScreensaver = ref(false);

const muteButtonHide = ref(false);

let player = null;


const startScreensaver = () => {
  showScreensaver.value = true;

  setTimeout(() => {
    const videoContainer = document.getElementById("vimeo-player");
    player = new Player(videoContainer);

    player.setMuted(true);
    player.setVolume(0);
    player.play();
  }, 2000);
};


const toggleMute = () => {
  if (player) {
    player.setMuted(false);
    player.setVolume(1);
    muteButtonHide.value = true;
  }
};

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fantastic. I just had to add `allow="autoplay"` to the iframe.